# Changing css class property to make a new css class

Tags: css

I have a css class which replaces the browser checkbox to a custom styled css

```
.dialog__description__checkbox>input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  padding: 0 0.5% 0 0.5%;
  width: 19.23px;
  height: 19.23px;
  color: #162f3f;
  border: 0.75px solid #ffffff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  appearance: none;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background 175ms cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.1, 0.25, 1);

  &::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    top: 4px;
    left: 7px;
    width: 4px;
    height: 9px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #162f3f;
    border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }

  &:checked {
    color: #162f3f;
    border-color: #ffffff;
    background: #ffffff;

    &::before {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    ~label::before {
      clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
    }
  }
}
```

I need to create a css class with a change in just background color property to.

```
border-color: #09C0D7;
background: #09C0D7;
```

what I have tried

```
.checkbox__dashboard>input[type="checkbox"] {
@extend .dialog__description__checkbox;
   &:checked {
    color: #162f3f;
    border-color:#09C0D7;
    background:#09C0D7;

    &::before {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    ~label::before {
      clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
    }
  }
}
```

but this doesn't seems to work is there a work around for this?

Comment: You didn't include the html adding some confusion. In the first rules set you target `.dialog__description__checkbox > input[type="checkbox"] ` and in the second you target `.checkbox__dashboard > input[type="checkbox"]`. Plus that's not vanilla css but SCSS and makes harder to deal with it when trying to diagnose or show evidence. One last note, `::before` and `::after` can't support `<input>` because they are void elements with no content

Comment: Could also be PostCSS, but yes - certainly not vanilla CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the selectors and use CSS custom variables to achieve your goal:

```css
.dialog__description__checkbox>input[type="checkbox"],
.checkbox__dashboard>input[type="checkbox"] {
  --checked-border: #ffffff
  --checked-background: #ffffff

  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  padding: 0 0.5% 0 0.5%;
  width: 19.23px;
  height: 19.23px;
  color: #162f3f;
  border: 0.75px solid #ffffff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  appearance: none;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background 175ms cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.1, 0.25, 1);

  &::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    top: 4px;
    left: 7px;
    width: 4px;
    height: 9px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #162f3f;
    border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }

  &:checked {
    color: #162f3f;
    border-color: var(--checked-border);
    background: var(--checked-background);

    &::before {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    ~label::before {
      clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
    }
  }
}

.checkbox__dashboard>input[type="checkbox"] {
  --checked-border: #09C0D7
  --checked-background: #09C0D7
}
```